# You don't have permission to access ... on this server: API call issue

Tags: curl, cookies, httprequest, setcookie

I am trying to call this endpoint using a get request.

`https://disneyland.disney.go.com/availability-calendar/api/calendar?segment=ticket&startDate=2022-09-01&endDate=2022-09-30`

When using Postman with no auth headers, and only a 'Host' header, the request is successful and returns back a 200 response with a proper body.

Postman Image Preview

[image: 1]

Example Body:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-09-01",
        "availability": "full",
        "parks": [
            "DLR_CA",
            "DLR_DP"
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-09-02",
        "availability": "full",
        "parks": [
            "DLR_CA",
            "DLR_DP"
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-09-03",
        "availability": "full",
        "parks": [
            "DLR_CA",
            "DLR_DP"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, using the same request in cURL or another HTTP client, I am getting a 403 response with the following:

request: `curl --location --request GET 'https://disneyland.disney.go.com/availability-calendar/api/calendar?segment=ticket&startDate=2022-09-01&endDate=2022-09-30'`

response:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;disneyland&#46;disney&#46;go&#46;com&#47;availability&#45;calendar&#47;api&#47;calendar&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;b5fa3b17&#46;1661136664&#46;2e1059d6
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am just confused on why the request would work in Postman and not in cURL, is Postman sending some sort of required cookie or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in your guess. In Postman, if you click "Cookies" under the send button, you will see there are already some cookies saved.

Disney is using a service like Akamai to prevent bots / scrapers from overwhelming their server. When you make a request, they will respond with a few required parameters e.g. _abck, ak_bmsc, bm_sz, etc.

Without these parameters, your request is blocked (hence, what you see when you cURL the page).